# Excel fila con información más reciente

Tags: excel, formulas

tengo una tabla que lista información de la siguiente manera

| Identificador | Cant Pasos | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 91450 | 3 | 15/01/2022 |
| 91450 | 2 | 17/01/2022 |
| 91450 | 5 | 19/01/2022 |
| 91452 | 8 | 15/01/2022 |
| 91452 | 3 | 16/01/2022 |
| 91452 | 8 | 21/01/2022 |

Mi objetivo es obtener en otra tabla un único registro por "identificador" que corresponda al más reciente, sin embargo no logro comprender como puedo obtener para cada identificador, la fila con la fecha más reciente.

| Identificador | Cant Pasos | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 91450 | 5 | 19/01/2022 |
| 91452 | 8 | 21/01/2022 |

Answer (score 0):

Con lo fácil que sería en Access :)

Se me ocurre que puedes hacer una tabla dinámica para obtener las fechas más recientes y `=BUSCARV(C4;Hoja1!D:E;2;FALSO)` para localizar a cuantos pasos correspondería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo de combinar con dos campos lo he obtenido de [aquí](https://exceltotal.com/buscarv-con-dos-o-mas-criterios-de-busqueda/).

Espero que te haya resultado útil, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes Excel 365 puedes beneficiarte de un par de funciones muy útiles:

> [MAX.SI.CONJUNTO (función
> MAX.SI.CONJUNTO)](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/max-si-conjunto-funci%C3%B3n-max-si-conjunto-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)
>
> [Función
> FILTRAR](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-filtrar-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi fórmula en la columna D de fechamax es:

```
=MAX.SI.CONJUNTO($C$2:$C$7;$A$2:$A$7;A2)=C2
```

Si filtra por VERDADERO entonces tienes el output que buscas. Pero puedes llevártelo a otra hoja con FILTRAR. En mi imagen, mi fórmula en la celda H9 es:

```
=FILTRAR(A2:C7;D2:D7=VERDADERO)
```

Si tienes una versión antigua de Excel, el filtrado tiene que ser manual, pero puedes sacar la fórmula de la columna D con sumaproducto

```
=SUMAPRODUCTO(MAX(--($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($C$2:$C$7)))=C2
```

En cualquiera de los dos casos, siempre puedes optar por llevártelo todo a una tabla dinámica y filtrar por VERDADERO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate que yo he llevado los campos Identificador, Cant Pasos y Fecha al área de filas y el campo Fechamax al área de filtros. Y luego he filtrado por la opción verdadero. Así saldría lo que buscas.